# What are the metrics of log entries with Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I use Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE) to deploy my service. In the cluster, I enable **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** instead of **Legacy Stackdriver Logging** and **Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring**. With the legacy monitor, I can find the metrics of the number of logs with the name **log entries**. What is the corresponding metrics name with **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring**?

Comment: are you just looking to see how many logs are being ingested?

Comment: Yes. And I will also apply some filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to [Stackdriver monitoring](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring) > Resources > Metrics Explorer and  select "Kubernetes cluster" as a resource type, you can find a metric called ["log_entry_count"](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#system_logs-based_metrics) and select it. This metric is also mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-logging).

So - the metric you're asking about is still there - no matter if you create a cluster with **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** enabled or no.

Furthermore - it will still collect data about number of logs ingested.

**To be sure of the metric existence** and if it actually does work I created a test cluster with some back-end service which generated some log entries and then tried "log entries" metric to count them - it worked as it should.

Comment: I see the log numbers with **Kubernetes cluster** as the resource type, however, there is still no data with *GKE container* as the resource type if the cluster is created with **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** enabled.

Comment: I found it!  With **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** enabled, The correct resource type is **Kubernetes Container**, not **GKE Container**.